# Adding indianmeal moth larvae to compost

Tags: compost, fertilizer, worms

I feed mixed grains to birds in a pot. Today, I saw that the grains have turned smelly. I wanted to clean it and I found that there were a lot of small worms in them. A quick google search shows that they are indianmeal moth larvae but I am not very sure. They are like 1/3 inch in size.

I also have a compost bin with kitchen waste. Should I add them to the compost? Will they help or harm?

Video https://www.youtube.com/shorts/FMxmYzkW-bI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They won't harm your compost for sure. If they manage to finish  their larva stage, they will just fly away. Otherwise, they will just be eaten by some predators such as ants.

Usually, compost pile is plenty of life at the boundary where it is not too hot. All this life is also part of the degradation process.